# InjectionToken in Angular APP_INITIALIZER factory

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create an `APP_INITIALIZER` in my Angular 10 application, where the factory has multiple dependencies. One dependency is an `InjectionToken<string>`, but I cannot inject it the way I do with constructors. I get:

> Error in ...
> Decorators are not valid here.

Here's how to reproduce this behavior (see also [this StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q7zvrt?file=src/app/app.module.ts)):

```typescript
export const FOOBAR = new InjectionToken<string>('FOOBAR');

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class FooService { dummy = 'value'; }

function initializerFactory(
  fooService: FooService,
  @Inject(FOOBAR) fooBar: string,
) {
  return () => {
    fooService.dummy = `Changed ${fooService.dummy}, added ${fooBar}`;
  }
}
```

And then this in the `app.module`:

```typescript
providers: [
  { provide: FOOBAR, useValue: 'token value' },
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializerFactory, multi: true, deps: [FooService, FOOBAR] },
],
```

How can I `Inject` a *token* into a factory method with Angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `@Inject(...)`. The `deps` are injected "magically" in the exact order you list them, as arguments to the function.

So this:

```
 {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializerFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [FooService, FOOBAR]
 },
```

will inject `FooService` as a first argument, and `FOOBAR` as the second argument, into your factory.